# Is it possible to write a shim for a existing library that uses `document` and still keep it pristine?

Tags: javascript, react-native, bind, javascript-objects, shim

I'm importing a library into a ReactNative project that uses `document` roughly 50 times. Because ReactNative, doesn't use a `document`, I will have to rewrite these lines in order for it to work in a ReactNative environment. The question is..

Is it possible to create a shim so that the original library is fully intact?

I would have to rewrite lines like `document.body`, `document.createElement` and `document.appendElement` . I guess `document.body` could just be my root container class, and the other two methods are self explanatory.

Because I've never seen anything like this before, I'm only guessing. Would be possible to import the library, and then bind `document` as a ReactNative `component` so that the component replaces the document in all of its mentions?

[The JS file in question.](https://kandy-portal.s3.amazonaws.com/public/javascript/kandy/2.7.0/kandy.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to shim a `document` object in the global scope, I'd bet good money there is no way you'll get that component to work in React Native. It's too deeply coupled to native browser APIs to be feasible.

Instead, I would look into running the functionality inside a [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html), or finding an alternative solution to what you're trying to achieve.

It looks like Kandy, the library you are trying to use, offers iOS and Android SDKs. one solution might be to bridge the native SDKs to React Native.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm gonna try and wing it with a WebView.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Kandy has iOS and Android SDKs - maybe you can bridge them over to React Native

Comment: They say they have "SDK's". But they're actually sample projects with 2 year old .frameworks in them. Trying to import them results in all sorts of swift conversion errors. Quick question though.. I do see some info on incorporating pods into an existing RN project. Would it be possible to, instead of a Pod, inject in a .framework instead?